# Fix div on top of the screen

Tags: html, css

So, I made a navigation bar using the HTML `div` and `table` elements.

```css
.menu {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>About</td>
      <td>Login</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Of course, it isn't finished right now and please don't ask why I didn't use an unordered list `<ul>` instead of a table.

So, the thing is I want to fix this menu on the top of the screen. No white spaces left before the div. What is the CSS code for this?

Comment: did you at least try to google this ? i thnk no ...

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>About</td>
      <td>Login</td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... so easy. Thought you need to modify the div's style. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the  css attribute `position : fixed;` and `width : 100%` to display it over all the screen

Answer (score 1):

Try by following CSS codes:

```
.menu {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```